# Error: No default engine was specified and no extension was provided. in the browser

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, ejs, template-engine

I am using mongo with node.js, I am using mongodb npm package to connect with db and my code as follows.

```
var express = require('express');
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/STUDENT";

var app = express();


MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {

  console.log("Connected correctly to server");
  findDOcuments(db);
  db.close();
});

var entireDoc = '';
var data = function(data, id){
  if(id == 'records'){
    entireDoc = JSON.stringify(data);
  }
}

var findDOcuments = function(db) {
  // Get the records collection 
  var collection = db.collection('records');
  // Find some records 
  collection.find({}).toArray(function(err, docs) {
    console.log("Found the following records");
    console.log(docs);
    data(docs,'records');
  });
}

app.get('/getInfo', function(req, res){
  res.render(entireDoc);
})
app.listen(3000);
```

The above code while rendering in browser throwing the above error in the browser. Can any one help in this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify express what typ eof view engine you are working with. for example ejs, jade, pub, handlebars or plain html..

Add following in your code below middlewares :

// views directory will be project_folder/views. So basically when you give a template file name to render, it should know where to find this. So below path is set.

```
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
```

//specify view engine and also to use it you need to install like npm install --save ejs

```
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
```

So when you say res.render('products');

It will search for a product.ejs file inside project_folder/views/

Further if you want to send direct string, you can use res.send() or if you want to send json, you can use res.json(). Render is used to render a view template from view engine

Answer (score 1):

```
app.use(
    express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public'), {
        etag: false
    })
);
```

Comment: Answers should always include some explanation not just a code snippet